# How to use negative glob pattern?

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps, service-worker-config

Our build generates e2015 and es5 bundles - e.g. in the dist dir we will have files like these:

```
/common-es2015.7765e11579e6bbced8e8.js
/common-es5.7765e11579e6bbced8e8.js
/custom.js
```

We want to configure ngsw-config.json to prefretch all js files except with `es5` in the name.

The glob patterns we have tried so far do not work - but they work when we use this online-tester

[Example](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tools/glob?comments=true&glob=%2F%21%28%2Aes5%29%2A.js&matches=false&tests=%2Fcommon-es2015.7765e11579e6bbced8e8.js&tests=%2Fcommon-es5.7765e11579e6bbced8e8.js&tests=%2Fcustom.js&tests=%2Ffavicon.ico):
pattern: `/!(*es5)*.js`

Test strings:

```
/common-es2015.7765e11579e6bbced8e8.js
/common-es5.7765e11579e6bbced8e8.js
/custom.js
/favicon.ico
```

correctly selects `common-es2015*` and `custom.js`

But when we use the same pattern in `ngsw-config.json` it does not work - e.g.

```
{
  "assetGroups": [
    {
      "name": "app",
      "installMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": ["/favicon.ico", "/index.html", "/*.css", "/!(*es5)*.js"]
      }
    },
```

According to the [angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-config#service-worker-configuration) negative globs should be supported.

What's wrong with this pattern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a good solution [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/31256#issuecomment-506507021)

the idea is to first include all js files and then exclude es5 files:

```json
{
  "assetGroups": [
    {
      "name": "app",
      "installMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": ["/favicon.ico", "/index.html", "/*.css", "/*.js", "!/*-es5*.js"]
      }
    }
}
```

then we can have another lazy asset-group for the es5 files:

```json
{
  "name": "assets",
  "installMode": "lazy",
  "resources": {
    "files": ["..", "/*-es5*.js"]
  }
}
```